# How can I cap my volume for above certain values?

Tags: windows-10, audio

When I am listening to something quiet and it suddenly gets very loud, I don't want to hear it as loudly.

Is there a program or setting that actively adjusts volume according to how loud currently playing sound is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has an in built feature called "Windows Loudness Equalization".

It can be found under Enhancements in the Playback devices menu.
Select the sound device you want to enable the equalizer for and click the Properties button.

[Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/115656/3-ways-to-normalize-sound-volume-on-your-pc/) are some other options too.

Comment: I was hoping for more but it's definitely better. Thanks.